# Is MacBook Pro timestamp of pictures 100% accurate?

Tags: macos, macbook, timestamp

A few months ago I let my housemate use my computer for a zoom class while I was out at work. I told her the password and since I trusted her I thought she would use it only for that purpose and day. A few days ago I came home and she was using my computer again, but this time she didn't ask for permission. So I wondered if she browsed through my personal files. I know I have a file with personal pics that I didn't access since last year. I right clicked some of these pictures and the last accessed date was 4 of February. Last modified date was in August. And I'm absolutely sure I didn't open it. She said she didn't browse through my things and that I must have added or excluded pics from this folder and this might have lead to a change in the stamp. And the problem is I'm not sure if I actually added things to this folder during the last months. I'm not an expert on this and would like to know if this stamp is 100% accurate so I can confront her and be sure to not trust her with my computer again.

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information to conclusively prove it was or was not your housemate.  It could have been her, it could have been OS or software doing something in the background, or it could have even been you by accident and not realizing it.

If you want to properly allow another person access to your computer, you should either create that person their own account, or a guest account.  This will prevent them from being able to see other user's files - namely, yours.

Here is a [guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/set-up-other-users-on-your-mac-mtusr001/mac) from Apple on how to set up user and guest accounts.  User accounts persist.  This means they can log in and out, and their files are saved for future sessions.  Guest accounts are temporary.  When guest accounts log off, all the data is erased and when they log in again, its just like they logged in for the first time.

Comment: do you know which softwares could change the timestamp? I'm sure I didn't open that file.

Comment: @Maria I have no way of knowing.  If I was in your shoes and you wanted to let someone else use your computer, I would create a user or guest account

Comment: If I were in your shoes, I would ask them to "get their own computer", and literally drop the microphone.